# Android permission RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED vs firebase remote push notifications vs google play policy

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I've recently built a react native (web) app that uses firebase to receive push notifications. There are two different react libraries for this and both tutorials contains in manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

I wonder if this is needed or not and if it is save to have it in the app. Is it needed for remote push notifications function? And second question if it is save from view of Google Play Policy. I am asking because recently my app got removed from store for some violation of "Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement". It's not related to this, but i am asking about this permission anyway to not make angry google play again, because it sounds bit sneaky this permission in manifest.

I can mention both libraries / tutorials.

First one is this https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Second one is this https://medium.com/@yangnana11/how-to-set-up-firebase-notification-in-react-native-app-android-only-4920eb875eae

Btw i dont have any receiver like this in the manifest anyway. (Don't know how some library like firebase)

```
<receiver android:name=".Broadcast" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` is normal permission. It is alright to have it in the app.

> Though holding this permission does not have any security
>   implications, it can have a negative impact on the user experience by
>   increasing the amount of time it takes the system to start and
>   allowing applications to have themselves running without the user
>   being aware of them.
>
> Protection level: normal

This permission is required to set the alarms and other background stuff when the device is rebooted since all the alarms are removed after the reboot. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#boot).

Comment: Firebase library might have it in their manifest. Check merged manifest.

Comment: i dont see any intent filter for RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in the merged manifest so maybe the permissions is useless in the manifest?

Comment: Hard to say. Why was it added to the manifest in the first place? Was it asked from one of the libraries? If any library suggested putting it into the manifest, I'd leave it be.

Comment: It is mentioned in both tutorials of setting up the firebase notification working. Its not mentioned on the official pure firebase android tutorial though https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: It is being used inside `rn-firebase` library. There is a file `RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver` in the package and I also found a comment in `RNFirebaseNotificationManager` file which says `// Scheduled alarms are cleared on restart. // We store them so that they can be re-scheduled when the phone restarts in RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver.` If you remove this, your users might miss some notifications which were not delivered because the device was off. Don't worry Google won't get angry with this permission.

Comment: If the receiver is not listed in the manifest, check the official documentation in case you have missed something, instead of following the Medium article. It is unclear to me how that broadcast receiver will be notified.

Comment: you are right it is also mentioned in official react-firebase-native page https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android

Comment: Yes, I think the medium article is missing something. Check out this section in official documentation `Scheduled Notifications (Optional)`. They are adding a receiver to the manifest.

Comment: yes you are right i will look into it. althought there is written local not push notifications, but the code make sense for the reboot permission.